# Text in TextInput not in correct position on ios

Tags: ios, css, react-native

I have a `textInput` in a `View` which is positioned at the center using `flex`. the problem is, when you start writing in the `textInput`, the text gets centered, even though I didn't style it that way...

The initial cursor is at the correct position, but as soon as the user starts typing, the text centers.

What's weird is that this issue is only with ios, not android...

I tried adding a style of `textAlign: left`, but it didn't anything. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix that?

Here's a **link** to the project: https://snack.expo.io/S1PlOqFvN

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textFieldStyling} placeholder="Try typing something..."></TextInput>
        <Text style={styles.textStyling}></Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textStyling: {
    fontSize: 50,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  textFieldStyling: {
      color: 'blue',
  },
});
```

Comment: Look further into how flexbox works. The controls on the container affect the child elements. If I am reading your code correctly centered content is exactly what you coded. These styles `alignItems: center; justifyContent: center;` do exactly that. Great article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Simran hey! I don't think you are correct about that. It centers elements, but should not center the text inside a textfeild...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextInput in React Native does not have a close tag

```
  <TextInput
      style={styles.textFieldStyling} 
      placeholder="Try typing something..."
  />
```